# Pass binary from Jenkins host to agent

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, jenkins-pipeline

Can you pass a binary from a Jenkins host to an agent?

I've got Jenkins running in Kubernetes, and the terraform plugin installed on my Jenkins master with the binary located at `/var/jenkins_home/tools/org.jenkinsci.plugins.terraform.TerraformInstallation/terraform/terraform`

I would like to pass this to my Jenkins agent by configuring my pod template and mounting the host volume path `/var/jenkins_home/tools/org.jenkinsci.plugins.terraform.TerraformInstallation/terraform/terraform` to the agent's path `/usr/bin/terraform`

But this doesn't seem to work as expected

When I exec into the agent and run a `terraform version` I get the error `bash: terraform: command not found` indicating that it doesn't have the binary.

I can see a terraform directory mounted in `/usr/bin` but without the binary. What I expect is for terraform to be installed on the agent. But my thinking might be incorrect here.

Is it possible to do this, has anyone has any experience with this?

Comment: It needs to be manually installed on every node, which can be a maintenance hassle.  You can [set Jenkins to run pipeline steps inside a container](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/#execution-environment) where the image contains the tools you need, which simplifies this case.

Comment: This makes absolute sense David, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a @David Maze mentioned binary from [Jenkins](https://www.jenkins.io/) needs to be manually installed on every node, which can be a difficult to manage. However you can set Jenkins to run pipeline steps inside a container where the image contains the tools you need, which simplifies such case.

Read more: [execution-env-jenkins](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/#execution-environment).

Answer (score 0):

One alternative is to use the [slaves setup plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/slave-setup/). We use it to install and configure internal tools (and end)  on nodes bases on labels. A log less hassle than @Malgorata's (and our previous) manually copy approach

Not sure how well it works with Kubernetes as not in our configuration.